# PHP Curl progress bar (callback returning percentage)

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have implemented the curl progress bar using

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'callback');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE,64000);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

and a callback function.

problem is, the script is outputting the percentage on my html everytime like this :

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.2
0.3
0.4
..
..
..
1
1.1
```

How do i combine this with CSS  to show a changing progress bar ?

Comment: Hi @WarDoGG, can you please provide the full working example of the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a progress bar HTML:

```
<div id="progress-bar">
    <div id="progress">0%</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#progress-bar {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 2px solid #aaa;
    background: #fff;
}

#progress {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-indent: 5px;
    width: 0%;
}
```

And JavaScript:

```
var progressElement = document.getElementById('progress')

function updateProgress(percentage) {
    progressElement.style.width = percentage + '%';
    progressElement.innerHTML = percentage + '%';
}
```

You can have it output JavaScript and have it update the progress bar for you, for example:

```
<script>updateProgress(0);</script>
<script>updateProgress(0.1);</script>
<script>updateProgress(0.2);</script>
..
..
```

Note that you can't put each update in **separate** script block, because the browser will try to read the full script before executing and the progress bar will not work.

Comment: Awesome ! I cannot thank you enough.. You really did me a big convenience. Thanks again, friend.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, won't it clog my HTML too much ? with script tags ? Maybe overload the browser and crash it ?

Comment: Um. Maybe, because outputting a progress every 0.1 percent means 1000 script tag. Maybe you can set a threshould that updates the progress every 1 percent, so that there are at most 100 script tags.

Comment: Or just use the class which is doing it for you here: https://bitbucket.org/spidgorny/nadlib/src/8591997b496da2425ee7924166108037162bd73b/HTML/class.ProgressBar.php?at=default