# How to Showing Progress bar value Curl in view at laravel?

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5

I Have a Controller For curl a Url & a method handle progressbar.
but I can't get progressbar curl

```
public function postUpload() {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array('self', 'progress'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
}

public function progress($resource,$download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
   if($download_size > 0) {
        $var = $downloaded / $download_size  * 100;
   }
}
```

I Tried many Ways: like set Session in progress method & get it in other page or Cookie. 
Cookie & Session Doesnt Upadate And Return Default Value.

Thank You for help :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer will solve your question, this is custom solution, but you can easily convert into Laravel Standards.

[Follow Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705974/1216451)